# Entity Framework generic types

Tags: c#, entity-framework

Say I have these classes:

```
public class Message 
{
    public int MessageId { get; set; }
    public string Text { get; set; }
    public DateTime CreateDate { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<Media> Media{ get; set; }
}

public class Image
{
    public int ImageId { get; set; }
}

public class Video
{
    public int VideoId { get; set; }
}
```

I want the collection `Media` in the `Message` class to be able to hold videos and images. How would I go about doing this?

I suspect I need to create a list for each type of media that could be used. I'm hoping a cleaner solution exists.

Comment: having a collection to be able to hold Videos and or Images in not clean solution. cleaner solution is to have separate collection for videos and images... btw that's possible if Video and Image inherit same class like `Media`.

Comment: @M.kazemAkhgary ah okay, thanks

Comment: Yeah I agree with @M.kazemAkhgary, that would just create a nightmare to maintain.

Answer (score 0):

If you are thinking about a generic implementation then consider an IMedia interface with a Media base class.

For example:

```
public interface IMedia
{
    public readonly IEnumerable<MediaResource> MediaResources {get; set;}
}

public interface IMediaResource<T> where T: class
{
    public Type MediaId;
    public void SetMedia<T>(int mediaId);
}

public class MediaResource<T> : IMediaResource<T> //Container for a media resource
{
    public Type mediaType { get; private set;}
    public int mediaId {get; private set;}

    public void SetMedia<T>(int mediaId)
    {
        this.mediaType = typeof(T);
        this.mediaId = mediaId;
    }
}

public class Media : IMedia
{
    public readonly IEnumerable<MediaResource> MediaResources {get; set;}
}
```

T is a generic type. You can use a class like Image, Bitmap etc or anything else really. This could contain anything. You could add a limitation on T so that its not just class, but derives from a base media type.